# Como fazer uma pesquisa pelo input text do html?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html5

Quero fazer algo tal como o Google, onde você começa a digitar e vai aparecendo a lista de opções de acordo com o que você inseriu, onde estas opções já estão cadastradas no banco de dados...

EXEMPLO: 
Um sistema de lanchonete, onde começa a digitar "COX" e já apareça todas as opções que começam com estas letras, como 'coxinha', 'coxinha de frango', 'coxinha de frango com catupiri' e afins... 
Ou até mesmo digitando apenas a ID da opção que a pessoa deseja e já cai no produto..

O que é necessário? Como fazer isso?

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88774/jquery-autocomplete

Comment: como alternativa tem tambem o [typeahead do twitter](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/)

Answer (score 0):

Tens de ter um `input` com `id='search_input'`, por exemplo, onde possas digitar o nome ou ID do produto.
 Depois tens uma `table` onde estão todos os produtos e seus respectivos ID's, neste caso dei um `id='tabela-produtos'` à tabela.

```
$('#search_input').bind('keyup click change',function(){
    search = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    var re = new RegExp(search, 'g');

    $('#tabela-produtos tbody tr').each(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        target = $(this).find('td').text().toLowerCase();
        if(target.match(re) || target.match('^' + search)){
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Neste caso, o código vai buscar o valor que introduzes no `input`, converte as maiúsculas para minúsculas (se for o caso), depois vai correr cada `tr` da tabela dos produtos e procurar em cada `td` uma correspondência para o valor/texto que introduziste no `input`.

Ao correr cada `tr`, estes são escondidos e só são mostrados os que tiverem correspondência com o valor do `input`.